# How To Check if a Partial String Exist in Another Partial of a String?

Tags: vba, string, find

I have the following example:

`String 1 = "AA.BB.CD.XY.D1"`

`String 2 = "FF.GG.AA.XYZ.12"`

I need a statement that returns `TRUE` if any partial of `string 1` is found in `string 2`, which in my above example, it should return **TRUE** because both strings contain `AA`. Note that order and length of each string is random. HOWEVER, the `.` operator is guaranteed to be there, separating each string into sub parts.

Comment: use split() on each string then nest two loops, one looping the first and the second looping the second.  If any match is found exit function and return TRUE.

Comment: Use the `split`-function on the string 1. Then use a loop over the pieces. Either use the `Instr`-function or split the second string also and use 2 nested loops

Comment: I will look into `split`. Will update once I get the results. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use it as a Function:
(note that it will match XY in XYZ. That's OK?)

```
Option Explicit

Sub fnTest()
    Dim str1 As String
    Dim str2 As String
    
    str1 = "AA.BB.CD.XY.D1"
    str2 = "FF.GG.AA.XYZ.12"
    
    MsgBox fnFindStrInStr(str1, str2)
    
End Sub

Function fnFindStrInStr(ByVal str1 As String, ByVal str2 As String) As Boolean

    Dim intSplit As Integer


    For intSplit = 0 To Len(str1) - Len(VBA.Replace(str1, ".", ""))-1
        If InStr(str2, Split(str1, ".")(intSplit)) > 0 Then
            fnFindStrInStr = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

Comment: Your solution is much cleaner than what I have and it works! Thank you,